# What will happen when an object temperature rise but don't stop?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, plasma-physics

Like a substance heat in state of solids at a  certain point covert into liquid, gas and plasma and my question is what will happen when we heat plasma continuously with rising temperature

Comment: Welcome to physics stack exchange! Right now it is unclear what you are asking so it is unlikely you will get a satisfactory answer. Do you want to know if there's a phase beyond plasma? Do you want to know if there's a maximum temperature a material can achieve?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Planck_temperature